# jQuery fancyBox for Soundcloud tracks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using jQuery fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ for soundcloud tracks in my web application where it is not working. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QNHN5/106/

The soundcloud url is `http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/53816732&show_artwork=true`

It shows this error

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

Could anyone tell me the mistake I've done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are opening an external site, fancybox should be opened in `iframe` mode.

You either add the class `fancybox.iframe` to your selector like

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" ....
```

or add `type: "iframe"` to your fancybox script options

```
$(".fancybox")
 .attr('rel', 'gallery')
 .fancybox({
  type: "iframe",
  beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
   }
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [Getting a "The requested content cannot be loaded" with fancy box (no errors in console though)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966547/getting-a-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-with-fancy-box-no-errors-in)

You just need two more things:

1). add the fancybox-media helper js file like (check your own path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2.0.6/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

2). add the helpers media option to your script:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    padding: 0, //<-- notice I added a comma here ;)
    helpers : {
     media : {}
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case is better to refer to that post via the comments section

Comment: In this case, that solution doesn't apply since that media format is not supported by the fancybox-media js file. You can check the source of that file to see what formats are supported.