# Fancybox opens blank page with youtube api

Tags: javascript, fancybox, youtube-api

Fancybox is working fine when I am putting a link like 
"http://www.youtube.com/embed/WQNQU_EQy6I" 
but I am fetching videos from a youtube channel and videos' links are like
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Neff9scaCCI&feature=youtube_gdata" 
and fancybox is not working with these links.

Please help.

JS -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".various").fancybox({
                    maxWidth    : 800,
                    maxHeight   : 600,
                    fitToView   : false,
                    width       : '70%',
                    height      : '70%',
                    autoSize    : false,
                    closeClick  : false,
                    openEffect  : 'elastic',
                    closeEffect : 'none'
                });
            });
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Neff9scaCCI&feature=youtube_gdata">Video</a>
```

**SOLUTION:**
I used this to solve the problem. $vd has the video's url stored in it and by this code I converted that link to the working one.

```
$vd = preg_replace('/.+(\?|&)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*/', 'http://youtube.com/embed/$2', $vd);
```

And then used it

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="<?php echo $vd;?>">Video</a>
```

Hope it helps someone like me searching for a solution to this problem.

Comment: your solution could have been simpler if you just have added the fancybox media helper .... check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10972551/1055987

Comment: I tried that but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fancybox media function.  Try changing your JS to:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
```

And try changing the link to:

`<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Video</a>`

For more info go check out fancybox website: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

I hope that this helps!